# Outputting the count in a foreach function

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with SimplePie and I cannot figure out how to output the count, or the key values for the loop.

Shouldn't this

```
<?php foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item): ?>
        <?php
                $i = key($item);
                echo $i;
        ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

, or this

```
<?php foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item): ?>
        <?php
                $i = count($item);
                echo $i;
        ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

be outputting a unique number for each?

uniqid() Doesn't work in this case, because I am running the loop twice on the page and trying to match up one list of elements with another based on ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single argument used with `as` is interpreted as a variable in which to store the *value*, not the key. If you want the key, you need to use `=>` in a manner like the following:

```
foreach ($feed->get_items() as $key => $item):
    echo $key;
endforeach
```

As a sidenote, you're using `key()` and `count()` on an item in the array, rather than the array as a whole, which is invalid. As far as I'm aware, there's no guarantee that `key()` will work as you expect even if applied to the whole array. It's meant for loops where you control the iteration, as with [next](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php).

Comment: Completely right, except the advice you give about `key()` seems a bit confusing. The way in which the OP uses key() will not only produce unexpected results, it's flat out wrong.

Comment: @Mike Sherov Good catch, I didn't notice it was using `$item`. Answer updated.

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining that. I guess what was throwing me off is that key() and count() accept an array as an argument. I thought $item was my array, but I guess I hadn't defined it as such - correct?

Comment: @jaasum Correct. When you use `$item` after the `as`, that means that it's set to a single (next) item within your array on each loop iteration. Your whole array is only accessible through `$feed->get_items()` unless you store it into a separate variable first.

Comment: @Justin Spahr-Summers Makes sense. Just out of curiosity how I would have grabbed the array from $feed->get_items()? Is that just dependend on what the script's author has set?

Comment: @jaasum `$myArray = $feed->get_items(); foreach ($myArray as $key => $item):`

Answer (score 2):

To get the 'count' in a foreach you would need an extra variable.  Getting the key is easy and the same if the array is indexed in order instead of associative.  Here is an example including both:

```
$array = array(
  'foo' => 'bar'
);

$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    /*
        code where $i is the 'count' (index) and $key is the associative $key.
    */
    /* $i == 0 */
    /* $key == 'foo' */
    /* $value == 'bar' */
    $i++;
}
```

key($item) that you're using above doesn't work because you're trying to get the key of a value that no longer is associated with the original array.
count($item) is the count of a subarray $item.

Comment: Would this be so that it starts at 1 instead of 0?

Comment: $i still starts at 0.  The array could be 'indexed' with words if you so chose.  See the updated example.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [get_id()](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_item/get_id) method

like :

```
foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item)
{
    $prev_ids = array('guid1', 'guid2', 'guid3', 'guid4');
    if (in_array($item->get_id(true), $prev_ids))
    {
        echo "This item is already stored.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "This is a new item!";
    }
}
```